# Non-authorization custom page is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

I have two custom error pages; 404 and 401. 404 is working as intended, but 401 error is navigating to 404 error page. So whenever I click on a page when I'm not logged in I want it to show the 401 error, non-authorized. It keeps showing the wrong error page, which is NotFound.cshtml (404).

This is my UserAuthenticationFilter

```
{
    public class UserAuthenticationFilter : ActionFilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
    {
        public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            // Check session is empty then set as result is HttpUnauthorizedResult
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(filterContext.HttpContext.Session["UserId"])))
            {
                filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
            }
        }
        public void OnAuthenticationChallenge(AuthenticationChallengeContext filterContext)
        {
            if (filterContext.Result == null || filterContext.Result is HttpUnauthorizedResult)
            {
                filterContext.Result = new ViewResult
                {
                    ViewName = "NonSecure"
                };
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Error Controller

```
[HandleError]
    public class ErrorController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Error()
        {
            return View();
        }
        public ActionResult NotFound()
        {
            return View();
        }
        public ActionResult NonSecure()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

NonSecure.cshtml

```
@model System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorInfo
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "NonSecure";
}

<div style="background-color: #A52A2A; color: White; height: 10px;">
</div>
<div style="background-color: #F5F5DC; color: red; height: 170px;">
    <div style=" padding:20px;">
        <h4>
            Sorry, the page you are looking for is authorized. You need to login!
        </h4>
        <h6>@Html.ActionLink("Go Back To Home Page", "Login", "User")</h6>
        <br />
        <br />
    </div>
</div>
<div style="background-color: #A52A2A; color: White; height: 20px;">
</div>
```

Root Web.config

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRedirect">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error/NotFound"/>
      <error statusCode="401" redirect="~/Error/NonSecure"/>
    </customErrors>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms timeout="2800"></forms>
    </authentication>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <globalization uiCulture="en-US" />
  </system.web>
```

Comment: Try to route to your desired page using RedirectToAction

Comment: Just use the [Authorize] on the Controller or Method that you want.

Comment: Where do you want me to do RedirectToAction? @ShunjidRahman

Comment: Doesn't work, it keeps navigating me to the wrong error page. @Aizen

Comment: The thing you are trying to do in Web.config isn't gonna work because logically: If a user is not authorized and got access to enter into a page where he should not then that's not an error. If you build some logic to filter the HttpContext then you can easily redirect someone to your desired page. You can go through the solutions here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10955596/how-can-i-have-asp-net-automatically-redirect-non-logged-in-forms-users-to-the-l

Comment: The Web.config is all right. I only have access to my login page and I can't enter other pages as an unauthorized user. It showed the default non permissible error before, but whatever error I get now, it shows NotFound.